# plotting asymmetric errorbars using matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot asymmetric error bars which are really 95% confidence interval. The output that I get is not the desired outcome. I am not sure what part of the code is not giving rise to the desired outcome.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = (18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34)
apo_average = (1933.877,1954.596,2058.192,2244.664,2265.383,2265.383,2306.821,2534.731,2576.169)
std_apo=(35.88652754,0,179.4326365,35.88652754,0,0,35.88652754,35.88652696,0)
error =  np.array(apo_average)
lower_error_apo=error-((4.303*(np.array(std_apo)))/np.sqrt(3))
higher_error_apo=error+((4.303*(np.array(std_apo)))/np.sqrt(3))
asymmetric_error_apo=[lower_error_apo, higher_error_apo]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.scatter(x,apo_average,marker='o',label="0 Cu", color='none', edgecolor='blue', linewidth='1')
ax.errorbar(x,apo_average,yerr=asymmetric_error_apo, markerfacecolor='blue',markeredgecolor='blue')
```

The outcome is ￼￼[image]

This is quite unexpected. For instance, I intended to put a lower error for the first error bar to be 1844.723, which doesn't agree with what's shown in the picture. This trend stays the same with every error bars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time it helps to read [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar.html) which states

> `xerr/yerr` : scalar or array-like, shape(N,) or shape(2,N), optional
>   If a scalar number, len(N) array-like object, or a N-element array-like object, errorbars are drawn at +/-value **relative to the data**. Default is None.
>   If a sequence of shape 2xN, errorbars are drawn at -row1 and +row2 **relative to the data**.

You therefore need to use the values calculated from the standard deviation directly, instead of subtracting them from or adding them to the mean.

```
lower_error_apo=(4.303*(np.array(std_apo)))/np.sqrt(3)
higher_error_apo=(4.303*(np.array(std_apo)))/np.sqrt(3)
```