# matplotlib asymmetric errorbar showing wrong information

Tags: matplotlib, bar-chart, errorbar

I am trying to plot a grouped barplot with asymmetrical errobars. When the error bars a symmetrical, it's producing the correct chart. However, for the asymmetric version, the length of the error bar is wrong.

Here is a minimally reproducible code:

```
# test with code from documentation
men_means, men_std = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27), (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)
women_means, women_std = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25), (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)

# dummy dataframe similar to what I will be using
avg = [20, 35, 30, 35, 27]
men_std_l = [19,33,28,34,25]
men_std_u = [22,37,31,39,29]

df = pd.DataFrame({'avg' :avg, 'low':men_std_l, 'high':men_std_u})



ind = np.arange(df.shape[0])  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind - width/2, df['avg'], width, yerr=[df['low'].values,df['high'].values], label='Men')
rects2 = ax.bar(ind + width/2, women_means, width, yerr=women_std,label='Women')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('error bar is wrong for asymmetrical, correct otherwise')
ax.legend()
fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

I have tried the solutions from [Asymmetrical errorbar with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798492/asymmetrical-errorbar-with-pandas) (getting ValueError: In safezip, len(args[0])=5 but len(args[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3JFJ.png))=1) and [plotting asymmetric errorbars using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45423704/plotting-asymmetric-errorbars-using-matplotlib) (getting TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('< U1') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe')

Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question as I could not understand from the documentation what those lower and upper bounds of errors were. In the hindsight, it should have been clearer if I were not so used to with `ggplot` in `r`.

The matplotlib version of asymmetrical errorbar requires the the values to add and subtract from the height of the bars. **It does not want the user to provide the upper and lower values, rather the numbers that should be added and subtracted.** Therefore, I needed the following:

```
xel = df['avg'].values - df['low'].values
xeh = df['high'].values - df['avg'].values
```